Wheelchair accessible downstairs bathroom
I have an old property, 1948, where the ground floor level is 1.3m above the ground. I would like to build a guest loo below the stair well, which means cutting the floor boards and creating stairs down to the loo to work.
In terms of accessibility all access points to the house have stairs up to the ground floor, 1.3m above ground level.
Is there potential issue with this ito accessibility, considering the houses accessibility?

You appear to be asking if there are going to be accessibility issues for wheelchair-bound users of a bathroom that has stairs required to access it. Yes.

Generally speaking, single family residences have very limited accessibility requirements - e.g., minimum width of doors and hallways but no limits on stairs (there are rules about how stairs can be built, height of each step, etc. but not a limit on having stairs at all). Multi-family buildings (e.g., apartment buildings) and commercial spaces (office buildings, stores, etc.) often have requirements for wheelchair accessibility. More details would help and, in particular, the jurisdiction - country and possibly city/state/province/etc.

Do you want a guess bathroom anybody can access or make the home accessible for less able people?  Second case, a ramp seems to be easier than digging.
